# Not able to load WebView on button click

Tags: swift, macos, webview

I am trying to load a url on a dynamically created webview when the user clicks on a button but nothing loads.

Code :

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController :NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    @IBAction func mybutton(_ sender: Any) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let webView =  WebView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
        webView.mainFrame.load(request)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have to add your WebView as a subview of your ViewController:

```
@IBAction func mybutton(_ sender: Any) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let webView =  WebView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 400))
    webView.mainFrame.load(request)
    self.view.addSubview(webView)
}
```